# Weird behavior when switching view between C++ and QML

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5, qwebview

I'm currently working on a project using Qt 5.0.2 on an embedded linux (ARM Cortex A9).

The main UI interface is developped in QML but I need to be able to hide this view to show a QWebView directly in C++.

I coded a simple view controller in c++ who hide()/show() the QML view and the many instances of QWebView.

The hiding/showing method work fine but when i show back the QML view, it's very instable. QML object are visible (or not visible :p) when they should not and the focus are buggy too. Object are draw in the wrong position too.

I try several methods :

-Initialize the focus/visible property of the differents objects everytime I show the QML view.

-use .setSource() everytime before showing the view

-try to update() the differents object thank to rootObject() before showing the view.

Did anyone have a tips to make the QML view functionnal again after a switch to a c++ view ?

thank.

Comment: I tried with Qt 5.1, same problems.

Comment: Not sure if this is related, but I'm experiecing some similarly weird issue on an Ubuntu box using Qt 5.1.0 Beta 1. Trying to popup the on-screen keyboard (for a touch monitor), some component vanishes even if its visible property is still true and a button shows the wrong gradient color. This seems a weird bug, I'll try to check if it has been already reported.

Answer (score 0):

there is probably a better way but,

you could probably do something like this (I have not tested this):

note: if the slot implementation is wrong (bad math) it will result in infinite recursion.

```
//this code could probably be in the constructor
real widthOverHeightRatio = 2;//set this value to what you want, or what it is when user first presses shift depending on the use case.

QObject::connect(this, SIGNAL(widthChange()), this, SLOT(onWidthChanged()));
QObject::connect(this, SIGNAL(heightChanged()), this, SLOT(onHeightChanged()));

//don't forget to define these slots in the header

//implemented slots
void MyClass::onWidthChanged()
{
   if(width/height!=widthOverHeightRatio){
      height = width/widthOverHeightRatio;
   }
}

void MyClass::onHeightChanged()
{
   if(width/height!=widthOverHeightRatio){
      width = height*widthOverHeightRatio;
   }
}
```